# How to connect to the new assembla key?

Tags: php, rest, curl, assembla

The new assembla api provides by REST-access a new authentification. i would like connect with PHP and curl, but I am not sure how I can include the `api-x-key` and `api-x-secret` as options:

**The invoke with curl in terminal**:

```
curl -H "X-Api-Key: XXX" -H "X-Api-Secret: XXX" https://api.assembla.com/v1/spaces/XXX/tickets.json
```

**in PHP (my problem)**:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => ' https://api.assembla.com/v1/spaces/XXX/tickets.json',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => ???maybe???
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($response);
```

This is my first try, without the options from api-key/api-secret including.

Comment: Pushpush has the correct answer - however, if this is a website, I highly advise using one of the more robust authentication methods instead of the key-secret pair.

Answer (score 2):

Send those keys as headers. Try this:

```
$headers    = array('X-Api-Key: YOUR_KEY',
        'X-Api-Secret: YOUR_SECRET'
    );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => ' https://api.assembla.com/v1/spaces/XXX/tickets.json',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($response);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Assembla API in PHP:**

```
$headers    = array('X-Api-Key: YOUR_KEY',
    'X-Api-Secret: YOUR_SECRET'
);

$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => ' https://api.assembla.com/v1/spaces/XXX/tickets.json',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($response);
```

This code prints a blank page.
No response
help required please